# Convert big JavaScript hex number into String

Tags: javascript

I have a big hex number, **(not a string)**, something like:

```
var bytes = 0x8136ae64614c30da74d4412273bfb; // this is a number, not a String
```

I want to convert it into a String. `toString(16)` truncates it, so I get `8136ae64614c30000000000000000`. But I need the whole number converted into a String

Have tried `BigInt`, but 1) truncates and 2) would rather prefer one less dependency

Is there a way to just print that number into a String without losing anything?

Comment: Where does this number come from? `0x8136ae64614c30da74d4412273bfb` is already not that precise _as a number_. Using [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), `0x8136ae64614c30da74d4412273bfbn.toString(16)` or `BigInt("0x8136ae64614c30da74d4412273bfb").toString(16)` should work.

Comment: Getting that number from an API call

Comment: How exactly do you get a _number_ this precise from an API call? Are you sure you’re not actually getting a _string_?

Comment: No, it's a number. That's why I stress in my question that is a number and that I have already tried toString and BigInt...

Comment: See my edited first comment on how to use `BigInt` — it doesn’t truncate anything and it’s part of the upcoming ECMAScript 2020 standard. Again, it’s impossible for this to be a number. API calls usually send _strings_. If this were a number, it would be a IEEE-754 number, which cannot be this precise. Your variable `bytes` has _already lost precision_ if you store it like in your question.

Comment: 0x8136ae64614c30da74d4412273bfb is way way bigger than the safest number in javascript `2^53`. And `0x` is how the hexadecimal *number literals* are represented. Internally they are all stored as IEEE754 standard. You cannot get a *number* prefixed with `0x` as JSON from an API unless you get a string. As @SebastianSimon mentioned, you can send it in a string format from the API and use `BigInt` to use it as number without losing precision